# Getting $scope.users.length as undefined

Tags: angularjs

In getPagerLabel method I am getting undefined for $scope.users.length, Here is the code

```
    angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])
        .factory('Users', function($resource) {
            return $resource('/MY/system/users/grid');
        });

    function UsersCtrl($scope, Users) {
        $scope.pagerLabel = 'Showing 1 - 10 of 100';
        $scope.users = Users.get();
        getPagerLabel();

        function getPagerLabel() {
            ...
            var total = $scope.users.length;
            ...
            //$scope.pagerLabel = 'Showing ' + start + ' - ' + end + ' of ' + total;
        }
```

Users.get() return json data like this

```
{"page":"1","total":"1","records":"3","rows":[{"loginId":1,"fullName":"Test User"},{"loginId":2,"fullName":"Some"},  {"loginId":3,"fullName":"TesterM"}],"expired":false}
```

Comment: What does `Users.get($scope.grid);` return? a promise?

Comment: Question remains, what does `Users.get()` return?

Comment: Is it an asynchronous call?

Comment: Instead of `$scope.users = Users.get(); getPagerLabel();`, try: `$scope.users = Users.get().then(getPagerLabel)`.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes its $promise... whats that?

Comment: It means your function gets called before the data from `Users.get()` is returned, thats why its still undefined

Comment: @arturgrzesiak if I use .then(getPagerLabel) then it throws error method not defined

Comment: which method exactly: `then` or `getPagerLabel`?

Comment: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because Users.get() return an object, rather than an array. You can use `$scope.users.records`, or `$scope.users.rows.length`

**Update:** If the above doesn't work, then it could be that you're getting the data asynchrounously that's causing an issue. You could try using $q service for creating a promise. A promise is an object that you can use as you would expect, but where the actual data will be filled in when the asynchrounous call returns. In it's simplest form:

```
function getData(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     // async call, resolved after ajax request completes
     return deferred.promise;
};

getData().then(someOtherFunction);
//Angular also "understands" that it's a promise if you use it in a template like so
$scope.data = getData();
```

You probably want to use .then() like others have suggested above.
You can read more here: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/09/09/using-angularjs-promises/

Comment: In that case `$scope.users` would not be undefined, which it is

Comment: I can't see that he has said that users is undefined, just `$scope.users.length`. "In getPagerLabel method I am getting undefined for $scope.users.length". Maybe I missed something.

Comment: The -1 is not mine btw

Answer (score 0):

Ok this fixed the issue

```
Users.get($scope.grid).$promise.then(function(result) {
            $scope.users = result;
            getPagerLabel();

        }, function(reason) {

        });
```